# when i am taking the photo through camera it is reversing in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

**This is the code i have written for taking photo, after taking the photo picture is rotating**

```
const cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
 //destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
 // cameraDirection:this.camera.Direction.FRONT,
}
this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {

  let base64Image = imageData;
  this.image = base64Image;
  this.initia=false;
  this.ShowImg = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64Image;
  console.log("base64Image", base64Image);
  alert("Your photo is successfully uploaded.")

});
return this.image
```

Comment: its happening on some device.i already face this issue but not find any solution

Comment: I have got it. I have added the   correctOrientation: true, Now it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

please add  `correctOrientation: true` on cameraOptions it will help you